# Can JavaScript be used to obtain real-time GPS location data?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, localization

Is it possible to access GPS data (Country name, City name, Street name and house number)  in real time on a smart phone with JavaScript?

Comment: To clarify, "GPS data" is literally just the Lon/Lat coords. To get the "Country name","City name", etc. from this data, you will need to use a third party service.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Geolocation requires special permissions. Chrome used to allow geoloc to be more easily accessible but has since restricted most code from accessing it. Here are a few examples of things you can do:

Here is an example from Google. You need secure origin https, a map api key and likely permissions from client browser:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation#try-it-yourself

This JSFiddle uses an API and doesn't require permissions:
http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/

You can also get the client's IP address through PHP and then run it through something to match the exact location:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Just to add, you won't necessarily be able to "match the exact location" from the IP address alone. This can depend on the DB/service you are using, as well as how your ISP assigns IP addresses.

Comment: So there's no chance I'll get the address for my gps coordinator on my phone, if not https and "third person"? this is injustice, suction.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Javascript can be used to obtain real-time GPS location, *if the browser has allowed the website to access the device location*.

The following code obtains the user's location, and the function can be called several times. Each time, it should give the current (updated) location:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
```

How the location is obtained and what is reported to the website depends on the device and browser.

Interesting read: *HTML5 Geolocation API – how accurate is it, really?* [Part 1: Non-GPS enabled devices](http://www.andygup.net/html5-geolocation-api-%E2%80%93-how-accurate-is-it-really/), [Part 2: GPS-enabled devices](http://www.andygup.net/how-accurate-is-html5-geolocation-really-part-2-mobile-web/)

For more info, see:

- [w3schools: HTML5 Geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)
- [W3C Geolocation API Specification](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/)
- [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation)
- [Mozilla Dev: Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)
- [Google Web Fundamentals: User location](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/)
- [StackOverflow: How does Chrome know my geolocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633621/how-does-chrome-know-my-geolocation)

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. I did not read everything, but I looked at it mostly just by the coordinates. and later read it completely.
I want to get the user's location (country, city, street, house number) based on gps and put it in one input.
sorry for my English!

Comment: The solution I tested here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366758/geolocation-without-ssl-connection) is a https required. it works on a local network, but it does not work sharply. So today (2018) there is no solution that works without https?

Comment: @Xenophobe All of these used to work with HTTP, but Mozilla and Google (very rightly) now enforce HTTPS as a requirement. It's not that they cannot work on HTTP, it's that they *should never be*. HTTP IS NOT SECURE. All HTTP data can be be intercepted at various points. Transmitting data as personal as your real-time location over HTTP is a BAD idea, especially since [SSL certificates can be obtained for free](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access accurate geolocation data through a smart phone. You may consider HTML5 Javascript API. It can access the latitude/longitude data through various devices/browsers. To be aware, it requests the users' permission sharing the geolocation data, otherwise it won't be available. Furthermore, you can implement geocode API to convert lat/long to accurate country name, city name, and street address.

Hope it helps!